# Laravel 5.3 Form Builder Assign 'value' Dynamically on Select Options

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

How do i assign the 'value' on the Laravel Form Builder Select Options dynamically in my views?

Example:

Function

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = \DB::table('categories')->pluck('name', 'id');
    return view('link.create')->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Link Category') !!}<br />
    {!! Form::select('category', 
        (['0' => 'Select a Category'] + $categories), 
            null, 
            ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Result

```
<select name="category" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Select a Category</option>
    <option value="1">Laravel</option>
    <option value="2">Zend Framework</option>
    <option value="3">CakePHP</option>
    <option value="4">PHP</option>
</select>
```

I would like the 'value' of the Select Options to be identical to the Option Content.

Like:

```
    <option value="1">Laravel</option>
```

Should be like:

```
    <option value="Laravel">Laravel</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pluck only the `name`, you can do something like this:

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = \DB::table('categories')->pluck('name');
    // creates ['Laravel' => 'Laravel', 'PHP' => 'PHP'...]
    $categories = array_combine($categories, $categories);
    return view('link.create')->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just pluck `name` for both key and value

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = \DB::table('categories')->pluck('name', 'name');

    // Combine your default item
    $categories = ['0' => 'Select a Category'] + collect($categories)->toArray();

    return view('link.create')->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

Your view modified as below

```
<div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('Link Category') !!}<br />
     {!! Form::select('category', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Comment: Combine your default item with category collection showed above